# Set arguments dynamically with Promise.all().then()

Tags: javascript, dynamic, parameters, promise, arguments

**The code below works for me**

```js
Promise.all([first, second, third]).then([first, second, third] => {
  console.log(second);
});
```

I know that `console.log(second)` will give me the value with the key `second`.

**My promises are dynamically set and now it looks like below:**

```js
let collection = [second, third];

Promise.all(collection).then((collection) => {
  console.log(collection);
});
```

- In this example I set two values in collection. In real life it can include more or less values.
- When I use `console.log(collection)` it will output `collection[0]` and `collection[1]`. In this case I don't know what which value `collection[1]` is.

### Question

How can I, like my first example, have something like named dynamically arguments like `collection['second']` or similar?

Comment: My collections always include an identifier, since I want collections to be portable. So they should not rely on either the request or response object that fetched the collection to know what they are. Since the promises retain their order, worst case you can keep a list of what's inside `let collection` and map the names back to the responses once the `.all()` resolves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we want to access the value dynamically, set `collection` to an empty object first. Then, use the `keys` from `collection` to pass all its `Promise`-values to `Promise.all`. Then, map back the fulfilled values and then, we can access `collection`'s value by some key.

```js
let collection = {}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  collection[`key${i}`] = Promise.resolve(i)
}

let collectionKeys = Object.keys(collection)
Promise.all(collectionKeys.map(key => collection[key]))
  .then(values => {
    let collectionFulfilled = collectionKeys.reduce((obj, key, i) => {
      obj[key] = values[i]
      return obj
    }, {})
    console.log(collectionFulfilled)
  })
```

Comment: Yes, that worked great! You don't like to put `;` at the end of the lines do you? ;)

Comment: @JensTörnell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi/2846298#2846298  personally I like putting `;` , but some people like ASI.

Comment: @JensTörnell I used to use `;`. Since I learnt Kotlin (that does not allow semicolon), I decided that it just *looks better* (if that makes sense?) without a semicolon, so yeah no semicolon xD

Comment: @Keith I see. I just noticed that my Vscode automatically add `;` if they are missing. I guess it's the PrettierNow extension that does it.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your promises embedded inside an object with a single key, you could use that for it's name, and then with a simple helper function reverse the values & keys from this.

With the new ES6 you can then just pass like -> `[{one}, {two}, {three}]` etc.

Below is an example with a helper function called `namedPromiseAll`.

```js
function namedPromiseAll(named) {
  const pcollection =
    named.map(m => Object.values(m)[0]);
  const ncollection =
    named.map(m => Object.keys(m)[0]);
  return Promise.all(pcollection).then((c) => {
    return c.reduce((a,v,ix) => {
      a[ncollection[ix]] = v;
      return a;
    }, {});
  });
}


const second = Promise.resolve(2);
const third = Promise.resolve(3);

const collection = [{second}, {third}];

namedPromiseAll(collection).then(console.log);
```